# Viewing data from a certain linked field from mysql table in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm stuck in a place where I want to view the other fields of a mysql table when I click onto a linked field.
Here is the code which is used to create a field into a link

```
<td><a href="fieldview.php?id=' .$row[0]. '"><b>' .$row[1]. '</b></td>
```

Here $row[0] is the field named "id" in mysql table(exampletable) & $row[1] is the field named "title".
Now, at the "fieldview.php" page I used this code to view other fields:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM exampletable WHERE id= '$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo '<table id="customers">';
  echo '<tr><th>Field 1</th> <th>Field 2</th> <th>Field 3</th></tr>';
  echo '<tr class="alt"><td><b>' .$row[1]. '</b></td><td><b>' .$row[2]. '</b></td><td><b>Today!</b></td></tr>';
  echo '</table>';
}
```

But I get nothing at that page. Please can anyone tell me what's the solution?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Does the link you're generating contain the right ID? Does the query work? Are you calling `mysql_error` anywhere to see if there's a problem?

Comment: If you look at the syntax highlighting in the question, you can see the problem. jakenoble's answer fixes it.

Comment: What do you see if you do `var_dump($row)` inside of the `while` loop?

Comment: You'll also see the problem if you `var_dump($_GET['id'])`

Comment: You obviously haven't done one bit of debugging. You didn't look at `$id` or `$sql` to see if they contained what you expected.

Comment: Another problem with your code: `<table>`,the heading row, and `</table>` should be echoed outside the `while` loop.

Comment: I did var_dump($_GET['id']) inside while loop & echoed <table> </table> outside the while loop still nothing. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Try jakenoble's suggestion. if you dont see the problem maybe its due to how you construct your link in the first place.

try modifying to to something like this:

```
<td><a href="fieldview.php?id=<?php echo $row[0] ?>"><b> <?php echo $row[1] ?></b></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you connected your database ?

FIRST CONNECT DB!!!!!!!!!

Try Echo:

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

in your file.

**But I get nothing at that page. Please can anyone tell me what's the solution?**

Did you got the HTML table with nothing?

TRY the following:

```
    <?php
    // Create connection
    $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    echo $id=$_GET['id'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM exampletable WHERE id= '$id'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    { 
    ?>
    <table id="customers">
 <tr><th>Field 1</th> <th>Field 2</th> <th>Field 3</th></tr>
 <tr class="alt"><td><b><?php echo $row[0]; ?></b></td><td><b><?php echo $row[1]; ?></b></td><td><b>Today!</b></td></tr>
    </table>
    <?
    }
    ?>
```

If you get no data in your HTML Tables then run the MySQL query in your Query browser with the ID to find you have data for the ID.

Do specify what you have tried?

Comment: i did the connection part with mysql DB just like u mentioned. I echoed `$_GET['id']`. But still nothing shows! But i see a link address in my browswer something like this,

http://localhost/Project/Pages/Forums/fieldview.php?id=3

Here i get the specific id related to the link.

Comment: Can you tell me!! what your getting in this line <td><a href="fieldview.php?id=' .$row[0]. '"><b>' .$row[1]. '</b></td>   I me in <td><a href="fieldview.php?id=1"><b>' welcome '</b></td>  ????

Comment: what your getting in the echo id?

Comment: nothing in the page if echoed but i get the correct id in the browser's address bar.

Comment: use my edited code and let me know what your getting? forget about the browser bar!! there is some thing your missing in the page?